# Excel Formula - Extracting specific data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to extract a specific Figure from a cell but it does not always appear in the same place in the cells.

the data in the cells appears in different formats and i have three examples below

(24M UNLTD 10GB £29+£20 S1) 
(24M UNLTD+INS 30GB £34+£30 S6)
(12M SIMO 1GB £15 S1)

In the first two examples i need to pull the first £ figure and not the second and in the third example i need to pull the only £ figure.

I would like a single formula that can pull the data but if, not it is possible to separate the data by the first 3 characters in the cell so i can use two separate formulas.

Comment: Do you always have a '+' after the number for examples 1 and 2? Do you always have a ' ' (space) after the number on example 3?

Answer (score 1):

you may use something like:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("£",A1),MIN(IF(ISERROR(MID(MID(A1,FIND("£",A1)+1,999),ROW($1:$999),1)+0)*(MID(MID(A1,FIND("£",A1)+1,999),ROW($1:$999),1)<>"."),ROW($1:$999),999)))
```

if there is never a number with decimal point then using

```
=MID(A1,FIND("£",A1),MIN(IF(ISERROR(MID(MID(A1,FIND("£",A1)+1,999),ROW($1:$999),1)+0),ROW($1:$999),999)))
```

will do it too

> The formulas are array-formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("+",A1)),MID(A1,SEARCH("£",A1)+1,SEARCH("+",A1,SEARCH("£",A1))-SEARCH("£",A1)-1),MID(A1,SEARCH("£",A1)+1,SEARCH(" ",MID(A1,SEARCH("£",A1)+1,999),1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfect. Thank you very much